# How to deploy prefect workflow on azure web app service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, prefect

Can anyone has an idea about how to deploy prefect UI and backed on azure web app server using docker/docker-compose?

I need to deploy prefect workflow on the azure web app service.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Prefect blog has a post about deploying the server to Google cloud compute, the steps should be similar.

[Prefect blog: Prefect Server 101](https://medium.com/the-prefect-blog/prefect-server-101-deploying-to-google-cloud-platform-47354b16afe2)

Edit: As OP points out GCP not a docker instance. Adding links I found previously related to docker.

[PrefectHQ github issue, docker compose on VM](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/4066)

[Github users K8 helm chart configuration might help](https://github.com/szelenka/prefect-server-k8)

I can’t now find the issue on PrefectHQ github that specifically covered prefect server configs when runninng on docker, its a good place to look.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have checked this link, it's deployed on vm, but I need to deploy on the azure web app service.

Comment: Ah, i didn’t read closely enough. A good resource is the prefect-server slack channel. I picked up a K8 solution there from Prefect engineer. Ill edit the answer with link.

Comment: I have raised the question at prefect slack channel.